# Move through this period

Tags: word-choice

Can I use *"move through this period"* in my sentence? I added additional information for context.

> He drove a car when he was drunk. For this reason,  he is in jail now. He didn't stick to the rules. Now his family will not see him very long time and they will be worried. His family can visit him in jail and be in touch with him,  so he will be able to **move through this period** easily.

Comment: No, it doesn't sound natural. If he's in jail, he isn't moving anywhere! - and it's not likely to be particularly easy.

Comment: If I need to add information about a member of the family. Can I use such words as "mother", "father", "daughter", etc with the definite article?  "If the father is in jail his children must know the truth." Or "The mother should tell the son the truth." Or is it unnatural?

Comment: Yes, you can - but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

> He drove a car when he was drunk. For this reason, he is in jail now. He didn't stick to the rules. Now his family will not see him very long time and they will be worried. His family can visit him in jail and be in touch with him, so he will be able to move through this period easily.

As said by Kate in their comment to your question, 'move' will be incorrect here. You can consider the following alternatives:

- He drove a car when he was drunk. For this reason, he is in jail now. He didn't stick to the rules. Now his family will not see him for a very long time and they will be worried. His family can visit him in jail and be in touch with him, so that he will be able to **live through** this period.

→ **live through** - *to survive (an experience, a troubling time, etc.)* [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live%20through). 
Now, the adverb 'easily' won't sound good here, because it is not an easy thing to be jail. So I would suggest you drop it.

- He drove a car when he was drunk. For this reason, he is in jail now. He didn't stick to the rules. Now his family will not see him for a very long time and they will be worried. His family can visit him in jail and be in touch with him, so that he will be able to **endure** this period.

→ **endure** - *to suffer something difficult, unpleasant, or painful* [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/endure) 
Same point to note as above.

---

Call me pedantic, but I would use the sentence like 'He **had driven** when he was drunk', but it is not absolutely necessary to do so. Also, it should be 'Now his family won't see him **in/for a** very long time [...]'.

Comment: Or less formally "get through this period".